# Remove green from Linux Mint browser

Tags: firefox, linux-mint

When I use Firefox in Linux Mint, everything has a kind of green shade to it. The monitor is fine. I'm guessing it's Mint branding.

How do I remove it?

**Edit**

My original question wasn't clear - it's not the browser chrome that has the green shade, it's the pages themselves.

Here's a screenshot - compare with the [actual page](http://www.lovefood.com/guide/suppliers/11332/the-best-bangers-in-britain--), and you'll see what I mean. To prove it's not the monitor, I right click on the photo of the sausages (I bet that's the first time that word's appeared on unix.se.com!) and save the image to the desktop. Then I view the image by double clicking on the new file and it displays fine.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/y92fK.jpg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y92fK.jpg)

There are two plugins installed - `Mint Search Enhancer` and `Stylish` - deactivating these makes no difference.

Comment: A screen shot would help understand your problem.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more than a "green shade". That's messed up! Does this just happen in Firefox, or does it happen in other apps as well?

Comment: Other apps appear fine (the photo viewer for example shows the sausages in an appetizing pinky brown colour) - I'm pretty sure it's just Mint's branding, but it's a little harsh on the eyes! It's the first time I've installed Mint (I've used Ubuntu before), so I was a little shocked!

Comment: It would help if you didn't GIMP photos before you posted them. Very funny. Either that or one of your friends coded you a funny trojan you don't know about.

Comment: @NotaName it wasn't a joke, and it was a fresh install of Mint. I gave up in the end and installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I have mint and have never seen anything like that on Firefox, This seems very strange if you ask me, Something smells fishy here..

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a custom theme.  Click Tools > Add-ons > Themes and select a different theme.